# Default QLoggingCategory to be disabled?

Tags: c++, qt5

I use [QLoggingCategories](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY) in all my projects and classes now. It works great.

I disable certain logging categories using environment variables.

But I dont want to explicitely disable certain logging categories. Instead I want the opposite: to enable certain categories.

It would be nice if all my custom logging categories only show warnings, criticals and fatals, but not info or debug.

When using `Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY` how can I disable debug and info automatically?

In my case I don't even have `main()` method where I could set filter roles (because `qt quick app` and `qtest`).

Is it possible to declare the default visibility per class inside the `Q_DECLARE_LOGGING_CATEGORY` declaration?